# Как из цифр составить наименьшее и наибольшее число?

Tags: c, алгоритм

ввод : 7 4561501 вывод:  6554110 1014556. Самое простое сделал, а вот остальное не могу. Как отсортировать так, чтобы  число не начиналось с 0. (нельзя использовать вспомогательные библиотеки)

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main() {
        char a[1000];
        int dryg[1000];
        int c, n, j = 0, buf = 0, min = 0;
        int i = 0;
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
        a[0] = getchar();
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            a[i] = getchar() - '0';
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            dryg[i] = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                min = i;
                for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                    if (a[j] < a[min])
                        min = j;
                buf = a[i];
                a[i] = a[min];
                a[min] = buf;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            dryg[i] += a[i];
        }
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%d", dryg[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214722 ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите составить наименьшее и наибольшее число](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214722/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be)